# Getting ID1s that doesn't have occurrences on group of ID2s

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have two columns, ID1 and ID2. I want the query to return ID values where it doesn't have any occurrences of group of ID2s.

```
ID1    ID2
1       3
1       4
1       5
2       1
2       3
3       1
3       6
4       4
4       7
5       1
5       8
```

Suppose I want ID1 to return IDs which doesn't have (3,4,5) values, the result should be 3,5 here.

What should be the query in postgresql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID1
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID1
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ID2 IN(3,4,5) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f851/1)

This will return `ID1` values that are not related to even one `ID2` value contained in `(3,4,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

With a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
   id1 integer, 
   id2 integer
);
insert into temp values(1,3);
insert into temp values(1,4);
insert into temp values(1,5);
insert into temp values(2,1);
insert into temp values(2,3);
insert into temp values(3,1);
insert into temp values(3,6);
insert into temp values(4,4);
insert into temp values(4,7);
insert into temp values(5,1);
insert into temp values(5,8);
```

The query for the example is just:

```
select distinct a.id1 from temp a where a.id1 not in (select b.id1 from temp b where b.id2 in (3,4,5) and b.id1 is not null)
```

Comment: when I do this, entire records are not getting displayed. Once a part of it is getting displayed. I dont think this is logically correct .

Comment: It returns two rows with values 3 and 5 for column id1 with the example data. What else do you want?